# roslaunch "include" in a new terminal

Tags: ros, roslaunch, include

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
with "include" I can call a "launch" file from another one, but is there a way to run it in a new term window?

We can make it with "launch-prefix="xterm -e"" for a node...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203149/roslaunch-%22include%22-in-a-new-terminal/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2015-02-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want them in different terminals I suggest multiple instances of roslaunch. The xml gets evaulated and then subprocesses are run and monitored individually.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0